# Flutter iOS App Crashes on Launch from Device Icon, but Runs Fine from Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode, crash

I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter iOS app where, after installing it on a real device (iPhone 13), it runs successfully upon the initial installation using Xcode. However, if I close the app and try to reopen it by tapping on the app icon on the device, it crashes immediately. This behavior is not observed on an older iPhone 6+ running iOS 12, and the app also works fine in the simulator.
Even a simple Flutter test template crashes when launched from the device icon, working only when initiated through Xcode's "Run" button.

Comment: We need more info if you want our help. We can't just guess, maybe add some code? Some debug traces or logs.

Comment: This is always the case for flutter debug builds. Install a release or profile build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the application on the profile mod.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"To launch in debug mode in iOS 14+, run flutter run from Flutter tools, run from an IDE with a Flutter IDE plugin or run the iOS project from Xcode.
Alternatively profile and release mode apps can be launched from the home screen."
[github issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657)